# Free Electron-Bond Electron Interactions

Tags: electric-circuits, electrons, interactions

I am reading an introductory textbook on electronics: *Practical Electronics for Inventors* by Paul Scherz and Simon Monk. In a section discussing the motion of electrons in circuits, the textbook mentions something called *free electron-bond electron interactions*:

> It is likely that those electrons farther "down in" the circuit will not feel the same level of repulsive force, since there may be quite a bit of material in the way which absorbs some of the repulsive energy flow emanating from the negative terminal (absorbing via electron-electron collisions, free electron-bond electron interactions, etc.).

I have never heard of such bonds/interactions, and a quick Google search reveals nothing of the same description.

The description seems odd to me, since electrons repel rather than attract/bond.

I was wondering if someone could please take the time to explain what these are, and/or please direct me to a source (Wikipedia article?) on this subject.

EDIT: I wonder if this could be in reference to metallic bonds? Metallic bonds are formed by the attraction between metal ions (of which circuitry components comprise) and delocalized, or "free" electrons (which is what is pumped out from the battery, as a result of chemical reactions within).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of electrons in a metal: free electrons and bond electrons. Free electrons are electrons from the outer shells of an atom, they are delocalized. Bond electrons are electrons on the inner shells localized around the nucleus. I think, “localized” in this context is more popular word than “bond”. The Coulomb interaction between localized and delocalized electrons can (through a tricky quantum mechanical mechanism) lead to the fact that delocalized electrons become slightly localized also, and, thus, decelerated.

Comment: So, instead of "free electron-bond electron interactions", you'd call them "free electron-localized electron interactions"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I have no idea what the downvote was for (I got downvoted too).